# What's a way to create flash animations with Python?

Tags: python, flash

I'm having a set of Python scripts that process the photos. What I would like is to be able to create some kind of flash-presentation out of those images.
Is there any package or 'framework' that would help to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generate a formated list with the data to your photos, path and what else you need in your presentation.

That data you load into a SWF, where your presentation happens.

Like that you can let python do what it does and flash what flash does best.

You might find allready made solutions for flash galleries / slideshows. http://airtightinteractive.com/simpleviewer/ is a famous one. You can load your custom xml in it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any Python-specific solutions but there are multiple tools to handle this:

You can create a flash file with dummy pictures which you then replace using mtasc, swfmill, SWF Tools or similar. This way means lots of trouble but allows you to create a dynamic flash file.

If you don't need dynamic content, though, you're better off creating a video with ffmpeg. It can create videos out of multiple images, so if you're somehow able to render the frames you want in the presentation, you could use ffmpeg to make a video out of it.

If you only want charts, use SWF Charts.

You could use external languages that have a library for creating flash files.

And finally there was another script language that could be compiled into several other languages, where swf waas one of the targets, but I can't remember its name right now.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Ming](http://www.libming.org/), it seems to have Python bindings.

Answer (score 1):

[Ming](http://www.libming.org/) is powerful but you might not find it pythonic to work with.

I prefer [Haxe](https://haxe.org) for Flash work. (It's the successor of MTASC)